# Div inside div hovering in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

I've created a web page which has a div with id="x" inside another div with id="y". The inner div has display:none. As soon as the outer div is hovered the inner div's display is set to "inline". The problem is that as soon as the inner div is visible and i try to hover it the div disappears as it's display is again set to "none". This problem is only present in IE not in FF or  Chrome. In Firefox or chrome i can hover the outer div and when the inner div becomes visible i can hover it too.

HTML Code:

```
<divid="y">Blah Blah
<div id="x">Random Text</div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
div#y:hover div{display:inline;} 
div#x{display:none;}
```

Comment: you should mark an answer if one of the answers gave you the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you are hovering another object when your mouse is over the divx. You could fix this by having a hover over the divx also, to change the display to inline, that would also do the trick.

```
div#x:hover div{display:inline;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9zBbP/6/

That will also make you able to lower the size of your HTML and CSS, as you can combine the y:hover and the x:hover to the same properties in CSS, and you are only using 2 divs in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive if this will work but try adding another outer div:

```
<div id="y">Blah Blah
    <div id"anotherDiv"><div id="x">Random Text</div></div>
</div>
```

With a display of block

```
div#anotherDiv {display: block; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9zBbP/

Answer (score 0):

you just need to place proper doctype to make it work in IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

you should have a markup like this: assuming `<divid="y" >` is a typo.

```
<div id="y">Blah Blah
   <div id="x">Random Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#y:hover #x{
        display:inline;
    } 
#x{
    display:none;
}
```

could be achieved also this way